# Is there any way to be notified of new comments via email for a page on a WordPress blog without posting a comment?

Tags: wordpress

So, what I asked in the title above is only possible if one posts a comment on a WordPress blog page that accepts comments. I would like to be notified of new comments, but without posting a comment. Is this possible?

Comment: Notified how? By email? Or would RSS suffice?

Comment: Email would be preferable. Plus I did say email in the title.